# Can I use Grails in proprietary software?

Tags: grails, licensing

I'm trying to figure out the licensing consequences of using Grails as the base for closed-source non-free software.  This would be a server product that is downloaded and installed. Users would not have the right to redistribute it or run it as a hosted service.

Grails and Groovy themselves are cool:  they're licensed under ASF 2.0 which is great.  However, Grails has a billion dependencies and I'm going crazy tracking them all down.

Grails can generate a list of software that your project depends on by running `grails dependency-report`.  I'm going through that list of dependencies, BUT:

- Many of the libraries do not list their licenses.  So I'm going to each and every library and figuring out its license.
- I'm guessing `dependency-report` doesn't list all the transitive dependencies (libraries that THOSE libraries include, and so on) because they aren't fully specified in Ivy.

Has anyone gone through this exercise before?  Just knowing the end result would be a HUGE help.  Actually having a list of all the dependencies and their licenses would be a MASSIVE help.

Thanks!

Comment: Install the software package from a respected linux repository (like Fedora or Debian) and list all the dependencies using package manager. You can grep licenses from that using a script. Unfortunately grails is not in the Fedora database AFAIK. This gives you nice result but its not 100% accurate (licence errors can occur but its 99% correct).

Comment: Grails is a Java / Spring / Hibernate software framework.  I just  [searched the Debian repository](http://www.debian.org/distrib/packages#search_packages) and didn't see it.  If you know of a repository that contains it, let me know!

Comment: https://launchpad.net/~groovy-dev/+archive/grails

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I spent a day tracking down all the Grails 1.3.7 dependencies.  Here's the gist:

- Grails itself has the nice friendly ASF license
- Some subcomponents use more restrictive licenses
- However, none of the subcomponents use what *I'd* call a "showstopper" license like GPL
- **However**, some people WOULD consider a few of the licenses to be showstoppers, most notably the LGPL used by Hibernate.

Lawyers are scared to death of LGPL because it's easy for developers to make a mistake that forces the entire system to become open source.  Things that would trigger this are:  modifying any little bit of the LGPL source code, copying any little bit of the source code into your product, or linked to the GPL software "statically" rather than "dynamically" (that's a long discussion).

Because of this, some software companies and purchasing departments have rules forbidding its use.

Here's the subcomponents with more restrictive licensing than ASF.  LGPL's the worst:

- Hibernate (LGPL)
- A bunch of javax stuff (like activation and mail) under CDDL 1.0
- org.beanshell BSH is SPL
- javassist is MPL

Everything else is licensed BSD, MIT or ASF.  Those are fine.

Comment: I fail to understand how modifying a tiny bit of LGPL would force the licensee to release all the source code to anything but the LGPL-licensed component that was modified.

Comment: I've always been amazed at it, too, but I've encountered it again and again in my companies and seen it elsewhere.   A notable example was Oracle acquiring BEA and [scrubbing their source clean of GPL and LGPL](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2008/04/08/oracle_bea_gpl_lgpl_code_check/)

Comment: @Tadeusz A. Kadłubowski - it does not. Only derivate code of the LGPL'ed code need to be under LGPL as well. Linking against LGPL'ed code does not mean that you create a derivate. The license is pretty concrete: http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/lesser.html

Answer (score 2):

I should think that all of the Grails dependencies will be fine for use with commercial software since SpringSource sells commercial support for it. You could try asking them about licensing issues as they probably have it all figured out.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I use Grails in proprietary software?

Ask Oracle, Grails is running on Java. It might be restricted through higher rights so you might need to get a license from Oracle first to create your specific software with it. Better ask the vendor of the platform first.

> [...] Java specifications are proprietary technology that must be licensed directly from the spec lead under whatever terms the spec lead chooses.

See [Apache foundation resigns from Java community](http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/9200638/Apache_foundation_resigns_from_Java_community)

Next to that it depends on the license of the Grails package. It's released under ASF 2.0 as you write. I would furthermost assume that this license applies to the whole package as the website suggest, but you must check the whole source code on your own if you really want to rely on this, because the software comes with no warranty.  In case the Grails folks made a mistake in licensing it falls back to you in a larger share if the information they provided was wrong.

Keep in mind that you are asking about creating your own proprietary software. That's a job on it's own, your business, and you need to take care for anything legal then on your very own.

You can never rely to any comment unless it's one of a lawyer that is acting behalf of yourself for real.

There is one plugin that might be helpful to check upfront visible licensing terms: http://www.grails.org/License+Plugin

The ASF 2.0 license is a free software license, so even if you consider it "friendly" with all the attitude you show, keep in mind that it has termination clauses as well as the GPL / LGPL. Those are to protect the freedom of the software.

Comment: Yes, specific Java implementations are proprietary -- that's why people don't bundle Java with their software, but instead require that they be installed as a precondition to using their software.

Answer (score -1):

The [license](http://www.grails.org/License) at the Grails web site will surely have an answer.

Comment: As the question states, the Grails license you link to is ASF 2.0 and says nothing about the licenses of the things it depends on.